# How to set up a FreeIPA server on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, ldap, kerberos, arch-linux, freeipa

I am looking for instructions to set up a [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) server on Arch Linux. Unfortunately, I am only seeing tutorials for setting up a FreeIPA server on RedHat or its derived distributions. (And I'm only seeing instructions for Arch Linux for a FreeIPA client.)

Is it possible to set up a FreeIPA server on Arch Linux? If so, what are the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody is maintaining FreeIPA server on Arch Linux, thus it is not possible to set up one. There are ~300 individual packages which are required to package full FreeIPA server and without a dedicated team to make so it is unlikely to happen on Arch Linux.

Comment: Which FreeIPA server (e.g., Red Hat or Ubuntu or other) would be the best choice for Arch Linux clients?

Comment: Server is ONLY available on Redhat and centos, clients only need Kerberos and sssd (generally)

Comment: @JacobEvans is right that clients can be set up easily.  ArchLinux actually has FreeIPA client components already. As to the server, it used to be that Debian/Ubuntu included FreeIPA server (without some important components making multi-master replication working) but it was removed due to upgrade of Tomcat code which is incompatible with a connector in Dogtag. So CentOS 7 or RHEL or Fedora is the way to go for the server side right now.

Comment: That said you can run it in docker. :)